# Get HTML element attribute value using Request[]

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page where many postback clicks are there.
In this page many input elements there, which values are i am geting from server side using Request[]. like below

### .aspx

```
<input id="txtRefTypeCtrlType_3" name="txtRefTypeCtrlType_3" lastvalue="4" CTRLtype="4" style="display: none;">
```

### .cs

```
string strCTRLtype = Request["txtRefTypeCtrlType_3"];
```

now i have a scenario, where i need to get the CTRLtype attribute value.
Can we get the attribute value using Request[] or something else.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: You could put that value in an <input type="hidden" />.

Comment: yes, i can. currenlty, i am using another hidden input to get CTRLtype. i am trying for alternative

Comment: You could also try generating a json object and posting it to a code behind Page Method using Ajax. But that would be too much work compared to just keeping the value in a seperate hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get the attribute value on the server side because it isn't posted. The only real way of achieving this is to create a hidden field with the attribute value and use that:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctrlType_3" value="4" />
```

Codebehind:

```
string attrValue = Request["ctrlType_3"];
```